# Excel VBA CopyFromRecordSet Column Failure

Tags: oracle, vba, excel, remedy

I am using an ADODB connection to pull data from Remedy (Oracle) and have a bizarre failure that seems to be caused by two fields in the query. If I remove the two problem fields, CopyFromRecordset works without issue and I get data for all rows and columns. If I leave the problem columns in:

- Every Record will be missing data for the two problems columns and
  every column to the right
- The exception is every 93rd row (rows 94, 187, 289, etc.) will have all of its data

Things I have tried:

- Renaming the field names to see if that would work (nope)
- Looping through the records instead of copyfromrecordset (this works
  but is INCREDIBLY slow probably because there are 45 columns)

I have ruled out:

- The data in the field being too long (max length of 25 characters)
- The data in the field having invalid characters (half of the rows
  failing have no data in those columns)

Update: Code Sample

```
Sub GetData()
Dim Conn1 as New ADOBD.Connection
Dim Cmd1 as New ADOBD.Command
Dim Rs1 as New ADODB.Recordset
Dim PlaceHere as New Worksheet
Dim strsql as string
Dim AccessConnect As String

AccessConnect = "Driver={AR System ODBC Driver};ARServer=Servername;UID=UserID;PWD=password;ARAuthentication=;RNameReplace=1;SERVER=Words"

Conn1.ConnectionString = AccessConnect
Conn1.Open
Cmd1.ActiveConnection = Conn1

strsql=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value

Cmd1.CommandText = strsql
Set rs1=cmd1.Execute

Set PlaceHere = Sheets("Sheet2")

PlaceHere.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordSet Rs1

Rs1.Close
Conn1.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps you can update your question with a code example and more information about the data types of the columns of the Oracle table you are reading from.

Comment: Thanks, I added the code to my question. The two columns that are failing are varchar fields. (The same type as 30 or so other columns that are working)

Comment: I never found out the reason for this failure, but if you are having this problem too, use .getrows and manually transpose and paste the array instead of using copyfromrecordset.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this question is a little old by now.

Have you tried connecting directly to the actual database instead of using the ARODBC?
The ARODBC does some nice things for you like automatically translating selection fields and date/time fields, but you can do that yourself with a little work.

Going directly to the DB might make things a lot easier for you and would likely make this problem disappear.